# String в Dart Обрывается символом �

Tags: строки, кодировка, dart

Я новичок в Dart и не понимаю в чем проблема.
Есть строка М, она обрывается на символ �. Но если я разобью ее на строки А и Б, где A=M.substring(M.length~/2)
B=M.substring(0,M.length~/2)
и выведу их методом print то они по отдельности показывают целые части строки М
но если я соберу их в переменную var result = A + B; то result снова обрывается символом �.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  String M = "�";
  print(M); // �
  print(M.length); // 1
  String A = M.substring(M.length ~/ 2); // Получили символ так как деление вернуло 0, substring начал с нулевого символа и до конца строки
  print(A); // �
  String B = M.substring(0, M.length ~/ 2); // Не получили символ так как substring начал с нулевого символа и до нулевого символа (полученного путем деления).
  print(B); //  
  String result = A + B;
  print(result); // �
}
```